# Fullpage.js navigation one item won't get active

Tags: javascript, html, menu, fullpage.js

I have used the `fullPage.js` script on my website and I used the menu function which detects the active page. Unfortunately I am not able to successfully add pages to the menu.

The list items show up but don't get an active state on the `4thPage` when you scroll over them. I'm also unsure why the script uses `firstPage` etc for some items and `3rdPage` for others. It can't detect the `4thPage` or `5thPage` but it can detect `3rdPage`? What are the correct names for those 4th and 5th pages?

I currently have this in my code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thPage' , 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu'
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage"><h3>Ruimtevaart</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage"><h3>Informatie</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thPage"><a href="#4thPage"><h3>Werkwijze</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="5thPage"><a href="#5thPage"><h3>Referenties</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="lastPage"><a href="#lastPage"><h3>Contact</h3></a></li>
</ul>
```

And my sections are called `section0` `section1` etc. So I have section 0-5.
Before I had this and this worked until I added the extra sections;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu'
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage"><h3>Informatie</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage"><h3>Werkwijze</h3></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="lastPage"><a href="lastPage"><h3>Contact</h3></a></li>
</ul>
```

Why is this 4th page not showing up? The names are the same and stated everywhere. Am I overlooking something?

My full code is here; http://kellyvuijst.nl/FINAL/ in case anyone needs it.

Comment: I don't understand the edit, why can't I use '' to define names of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to add the `#` on the `lastPage` link of your menu. Also, don't forget that you still have to add the sections to your site `<div class="section">.....</div>`.

**Update:**
Your anchor is `4thpage` and the link is `4thPage`. **See the difference in the P**. Once is in uppercase and the other is not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the hashtag, didn't solve my problem sadly. I am using the <div class="section"> yes.

Comment: You are forcing the site to load on the 2nd section and that's throwing errors. Try removing that functionality first and see how it works. Then if it works well, the problem is in the functionality you implemented.

Comment: I already checked that, this is not the problem but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I belive I got it :), Your anchor is `4thpage` and the link is `4thPage`. Notice the difference in the `P`. Once is in uppercase the other not. Updated answer.

Comment: Gosh I can't believe that was the problem, thank you!!